# scrollLeft does not work in Safari with RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, right-to-left

I have issue with scrollLeft for Safari when page in RTL direction.
In Safari when i do click on button (that has a handler scrollLeft(-200)) i will scroll to 0 position of page. And this is big issue.

Safari: 7.0.1
OS: OS X 10.9.1

Following code has structure like as my page but more easier:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style>
        .main {

        }

        .content {
            direction: rtl; 
            width: 2000px;
        }

        .button-scroll {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, sapiente illo dignissimos odit nisi. Voluptatibus, temporibus, recusandae totam libero architecto veniam unde quod nisi facere perspiciatis fugiat harum odit tenetur.
                </p>        
        </div>
        <div class="button-scroll"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.button-scroll').bind('click', function(){
        console.log('scrolling... ' + document.body.scrollLeft);
        // $(document.body).scrollLeft(100);
        document.body.scrollLeft -= 100;
        console.log(document.body.scrollLeft);
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note, "<html dir="rtl">". jsfiddle.net uses just html without attribute "dir", but i need use it.

Comment: Looks like a browser bug to me.

Comment: I think you are right, but i need to find solution for handler of button.

Comment: Still not fixed in 2019. I think safari is turning to IE of the future :(